# Versioning records via extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase

TYPO3 has functionality so that it is possible to oversee changes that has been done to record via backend over time, as below:

[image]

Is that somehow possible to configure extbase so that records that are changed via extbase update function will be monitored too?